# Android Views Creation Callback

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

Am trying to get a callback on each view and it's AttributeSet, when created in the activity, I tried to use `LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory` with a custom `LayoutInflaterFactory` so I can receive all views created from activity LayoutInflater, but it seems it doesn't handle custom views and any kind of ViewGroup.

```
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    final View view = parentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
```

in the code above, the view returns null if its a ViewGroup element or a custom view (like support Toolbar).

so What i did is using some reflection to inject a private Factory into the LayoutInflater and it works fine (the same as Calligraphy library).

but am trying to avoid any hacky way, is there a better way to handle this?